# Conocer el tamaño de una array de 2 dimenciones en C

Tags: array, c

He intentado sacar el tamaño de las filas y las columnas pero no he podido.

```
#include <stdio.h>  //printf(...)
#include <stdlib.h> //EXIT_SUCCESS

int main(void) {

    int result[2][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8}};

    int row = sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]);
    int column = sizeof(result[0]) / row;

    printf("Numero de Filas: %d\n", row);
    printf("Numero de Columnas: %d\n", column);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
//Numero de Filas: 2
//Numero de Columnas: 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te equivocas en esto:

```
int column = sizeof(result[0]) / row;
```

El resultado que buscas lo abtienes al dividir el tamaño de la fila entre el tamaño de un elemento individual:

```
int column = sizeof( result[0] ) / sizeof( result[0][0] );
```